# Hosting an HTML page on a Meteor app

Tags: node.js, meteor, meteor-blaze, flow-router

I have a Meteor app and would like to host an HTML page.

I can put my `index.html` page and content inside meteors `public/main/` folder, so it would be accessible by `127.0.0.1/main/index.html`.

But surely there must be a better way. I have the Kadira FlowRouter package and Blaze templates if it helps.

I tried:

```
FlowRouter.route('/main', {
  action(params) {
    window.location.href=pathToPage;
  }
});
```

But it didn't work when moving my page out of the public folder.

The page itself is an HTML and javascript page.

Comment: If you want to serve it directly then yes, it has to be somewhere under `/public`. You can also use server-side rendering (SSR) to render an HTML file that's under `/private`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [`static-html` package](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/static-html).

From the package description:

> Essentially, an alternative to the templating package that doesn't
>   compile Blaze templates. Mostly useful if you want to use Angular or
>   React as your view layer and just want to get some static HTML content
>   on your page as a render target for your view framework.
>
> This build plugin parses all of the .html files in your app and looks
>   for top-level tags:
>
> - appended to the head section of your HTML  - appended
>   to the body section of your HTML Attributes are supported on the
>    tag, but not on .